# How to add padding to the data shown in MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I need to add a padding between the sides of the screen and the data being shown, but the zero line has to go all the way to the edge of the screen (see pic below). How can I do this?

[image]
I was able to add padding on the right side by using `setVisibleXRangeMinimum()` but I can't figure out how to either center the data or also add padding on the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method to set an extra offset to be appended to the viewport's left/right.

```
barChart.setExtraLeftOffset(5);
barChart.setExtraRightOffset(5);
```

Comment: Already tried it, that adds padding to the zero line too so it doesn't do what I need.